Proving $f$ is the Identity Function Given $f^n(x) = x$ for All $x \in [0,1]$
Let $f : [0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ be a continuous function with $f(0)=0$. Let $f^n = f \circ f \circ ... \circ f$ (composition n times). Proof that if $f^n(x)=x$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ for some fixed $n \in N$  than $f$ is the identity function.
I've been staring at this for a long time now and I'm sure the proof is super simple I just cannot think of it.

It's a good question, but the way that things work around here, people will ask that you give some idea of what you've tried. This site is generally allergic to "Problem Statement Questions" (PSQs) where the problem is stated but not much more is said.

$\mathrm{id} = f^n = f^{n - 1} \circ f$ implies that $f$ is injective and surjective, hence bijective. A continuous injective self-map of an interval is strictly monotone, and the condition $f(0) = 0$ forces $f$ to be strictly monotonically increasing. But then $[0, 1] = \operatorname{range} f^{n - 1} \subseteq \operatorname{range} f$ forces $f$ to be surjective, so $f$ is a continuous monotonically increasing bijection from $[0, 1]$ to itself. In particular, this means that $f(t) \geq t$ for all $t \in [0, 1]$, and if you assume that there exists a $t \in [0, 1]$ with $f(t) > t$, then monotonicity implies $t = f^n(t) > t$ which is absurd. Thus, $f(t) = t$ for all $t$, i.e. $f = \mathrm{id}$.

Let's assume $f(x)=f(y), x,y \in [0,1]$. Applying $f$, $n-1$ times to both sides, we get $f^n (x) = f^n (y)$
But according to the question, $$f^n(x)=x \forall x \in [0,1]$$
So $x=y$.Thus it's a bijective function.
Now let's assume that $f(x)$ is strictly increasing and $f(x)>x$. Then $$x<f(x)<f(f(x)<f(f(f(x)<...<f^n(x)$$
But $f^n(x)=x$. This contradicts our assumption. Hence $f(x)$ must be a strictly decreasing function or $f(x)=x$.
Assuming that its a strictly decreasing function, then $$x>f(x)>f(f(x)>...f^n(x)$$
But again $f^n (x) = x$. Thus this contradicts the statement that this function is strictly decreasing.
Thus this and the fact that the function is bijective proves that $f(x)$ is an indetity function, and $f(x)=x \forall x \in [0,1]$.

The identity function is an increasing function. The assumption you meant to make is $f(x)>x$.

You should probably mention where you use the assumption $f(0) = 0$.

Yes I didn't frame my sentence correctly. Sorry @Shean

@BenSteffan excuse me sir, can you please tell like where can I put it? I was thinking about it too. Like should I tell it as it's a given value of the function, it "verfies it " or something like that?

@Gwen Well if you don't put it then $f(t) = 1 - t$ and $n = 2$ is an obvious counterexample. Think about this and then complete your answer :)

@BenSteffan Okay I thought about it. I learnt about functions just a few weeks ago and it's just the basics. Please correct me if I am wrong. A function is continuous at a point, say $c$ if $$lim_{x→c^-} f(x)=f(c)=lim_{x→c^+}f(x)$$ If $c=0, f(0)=0$ (given). Thus LHL= $lim_{x→0^-} f(x)=0$ and RHL=$lim_{x→{0^+}}f(x)=0$ as well, for $f(x)$ to be continuous at 0.

@Gwen I don't see how this has anything to do with the question.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
